# Azure Function - Queue trigger process batchwise instead of itemwise

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

Is there a way to trigger Azure Function from queue and process messages batch by batch instead of item by item?

I have a lot of web jobs that use [GroupQueueTrigger](https://github.com/ealsur/WebJobs.Extensions.GroupQueueTrigger) extension allowing me to read batch of 32 messages from the queue and process them in one run (this has a lot of advantages, f.e. speeds up inserts to Azure Table by using batch inserts, allows me to localy map-reduce messages before further processing, etc.). I want to rewrite these web jobs to Azure Function but I don't like to give up on batchwise processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, but no, you can't.

Event Hubs trigger supports that (and it's the recommended way to use it), so maybe you could give that one a try?

UPDATE: There is [an open-source library](https://github.com/Scooletz/QueueBatch) to add batching to Queue triggers. I haven't tried it myself, but give it a spin.